# обращение к вложенному словарю, с неизвестным ключом

Tags: python, dict

по апи я получаю следующий словарь

```
{
    "error": [],
    "result": {
        "Apple": {
            "data": ["37410.10000","40.721",1700559085]
        }
    }
}
```

как достать словарь `{"data":["37410.10000","40.721",1700559085]}`, с учетом того, что ключ `"Apple"` меняется и по нему нельзя обратиться?

Comment: `for k in d['result'].keys():  result = d['result'][k]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно использовать `.values()`, тогда ключ не нужен.

```
d = {
    "error": [],
    "result": {
        "Apple": {
            "data": ["37410.10000","40.721",1700559085]
        }
    }
}

internal_dict = list(d['result'].values())[0]

print(internal_dict)
```